# Which character in Mahabharata was invincible underwater and to aquatic creatures besides Krishna and Varuna?

Tags: mahabharata

Besides, Krishna and Varuna, were there any characters in Mahabharata invincible underwater?

Comment: I have seen in a TV serial that it is Duryodhana.